# What verifiable reasons were there for adding display: table-* to the CSS specification?

Tags: html, css

I get that some layouts are easier to achieve now that `display: table-*` is available to us in CSS (such as the [Holy Grail layout](http://alistapart.com/article/holygrail)), but what were the reasons behind deciding to add these display options to the [CSS standard](http://www.w3.org/TR/CSS21/tables.html), given the well known historical hatred towards table-based layouts in *HTML*.

Any references to discussions, mailing list entries, specifications etc. would be great!

**I'm not looking for reasons to use the options, or opinions/guesses as to the motivations of the standards body.** Rather, why and by whom was it decided that including it in the standard had merit.

Thanks.

Comment: Note that I am not saying it's good or bad...

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The problem was not so that table based layouts were bad, but that tables were being used for layout. This kind of made it difficult to figure out which were actual tables (i.e. tabular data) and which were tables used just for layout.

Adding table-* to CSS meant we could move the layout based table-* to CSS and retain only the semantic tables in HTML (i.e. actual tabular data)

---

Here is the earliest reference to this I could find on the W3 mailing archives - https://lists.w3.org/Archives/Public/www-style/1998Aug/0091.html. (**"display: table" as a substitute for TABLE for layout**)

There is a reference to an older thread and you can possibly trace it all the way back, but the above provides enough context. An excerpt

> There are a lot of pages out there where blocks of content are
>   arranged for visual purposes using HTML tables.  This structure is
>   supposed to be deprecated in HTML 4.0, but in practice it is difficult
>   to work out the corresponding CSS construct, especially if the
>   TABLE-based layout was unconcerned with the precise width of the
>   cells.
>
> However, in the CSS2 spec
>   http://www.w3.org/TR/REC-CSS2/visuren.html#value-inst-table, the
>   following are listed as possible values for the 'display' property:
>
> table, inline-table, table-row-group, table-column,
>   table-column-group, table-header-group, table-footer-group, table-row,
>   table-cell, and table-caption

Comment: @PeterBailey - added a link to the discussion on the W3 mailing list. Cheers!

Comment: Thanks, I liked Braden N. McDaniel's argument for not bothering to add it in that thread! "We may agree that using tables for layout is bad form, but that doesn't change the fact that this technique is used quite liberally on the Web. IMO, a UA that assumes a table will always contain tabular data isn't all that intelligent."

Answer (score 1):

> ...given the well known historical hatred towards table-based layouts in HTML.

It's exactly this. The HTML `table` element is semantically intended to hold nothing more than tabular data; page layouts, forms, lists, etc. are almost always *not* tabular data.

The HTML401 Specification states:

> Tables should not be used purely as a means to layout document content as this may present problems when rendering to non-visual media. Additionally, when used with graphics, these tables may force users to scroll horizontally to view a table designed on a system with a larger display. To minimize these problems, **authors should use style sheets to control layout rather than tables**.
>
> — [Tables - HTML401 Specification](http://www.w3.org/TR/html401/struct/tables.html)

The CSS `table-*` display isn't intended to only be used with tabular data. It's designed as a way of creating layouts in a similar way as the HTML `table` element otherwise would with rows and columns. A CSS-styled table doesn't have to contain tabular data at all as it doesn't matter - it's purely visual.

The HTML approach isn't semantically valid. The CSS approach is.

---

As a note: The HTML5 specification does allow for the `table` element to be used for layout, but only if `role=presentation` is specified:

> **Tables should not be used as layout aids**. Historically, many Web authors have tables in HTML as a way to control their page layout **making it difficult to extract tabular data from such documents**. In particular, users of accessibility tools, like screen readers, are likely to find it very difficult to navigate pages with tables used for layout. If a table is to be used for layout it must be marked with the attribute role="presentation" for a user agent to properly represent the table to an assistive technology and to properly convey the intent of the author to tools that wish to extract tabular data from the document.
>
> — [The Table Element - HTML5 Specification](http://www.w3.org/TR/html5/tabular-data.html#the-table-element)

Comment: @PeterBailey I've added a couple of relevant quotes.

Answer (score 1):

First, for purely practical reasons: CSS needed a way to describe how to layout `<table>` elements. Without the `table-*` display rules, browsers had to special case the layout of such elements.

> the well known historical hatred towards table-based layouts

There are two problems with using layout tables.

1. Incorrect semantics. That isn't a problem when you don't use a `<table>` element but do use `display: table`. You can have a layout like a table without a claim of table-like semantics.
2. Rendering speed. That isn't a problem when you don't use excessively large tables or when you use `table-layout: fixed`.

So CSS addresses both the problems.

Comment: @Peter Bailey: The introductory section in http://www.w3.org/TR/CSS21/tables.html and the non-normative sample style sheet in http://www.w3.org/TR/CSS21/sample.html are as close as it gets to references within the spec. Section 17 doesn't outright state the motivation for these display types, but you can pretty much infer it from the text...

Comment: Thanks - yes the spec doesn't really lay out a justification, thanks for the sample link though, hadn't spotted that one.